# Change a label in a prototype cell upon button press

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have set up a tableview using custom cells as such:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{SWHNearYouCell *cell = (SWHNearYouCell *)[tableView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NearYouCell"];

SWHNearYou *aPointer = [self.thingsNearYou objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.customNearYouLabel.text = aPointer.restrauntsNearYou;
return cell;
}
```

I want to change the text of customNearYouLabel upon a button press but work out how to get a pointer to the cell in my -IBAction method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just handle that in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method by grabbing the cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.customNearYouLabel.text = @"New Text";
}
```

Comment: Was looking to do it in a bar button press - good work though

Comment: That changes everything. You just need to adjust your data when you hit the button then call `reloadData` on the table. Probably just have a BOOL that you set when the button gets pressed. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check the BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the button is not on a table cell?

If so, you just need to update the relevant value in the `self.thingsNearYou` array.

If you then call [tableView reloadData] then the table will reload it's data and the text of `customNearYouLabel` will change.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out - needed to add in self before tableview

```
-(IBAction)cancel:(id)sender{


    SWHNearYouCell *cell = (SWHNearYouCell *)[self.tableView
                                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NearYouCell"];

cell.customNearYouLabel.text = @"New Text";

 NSLog(@"This is it: %@",cell.customNearYouLabel.text);

}
```

I'll need to spend some more time on it as [self.tableView reloadData]; will not update the table but I reckon that should be easier to solve.

Comment: This is very very wrong. You shouldn't access the cell this way. Check my comment.